# Android app crashes when using appcompat v7

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

I'm quite new to android.
I'm trying to implement the google play style tabs application in android manager.
I followed this guide:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout

However when I run the app on either simulator or target it crashes while it loads.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you show the error message?

Comment: Maybe we can help you. But to do that you have to post some relevant codes and your exception log.

Comment: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Comment: That is the line in the logacat that explains the fatal error

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Forgot to look at the logcat.
I have examined it , and it turns out that I tried to cast linear layout to a text view.
Removed that code, which sourced from the guide I posted.

Do you know how the example casts layout to textview or is it a mistake?

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view;
    textView.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
    return view;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your *res/layout/fragment_page.xml* with the guide: there is not LinearLayout in the original one.